# validator html input type file

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, validation, html-input

How can we validate the html `<input type="file" />` from asp.net. I have tried `<asp:fileUpload />`it is working fine and I want to validate the html input. I have tried this piece of code :

```
  <input id="AttachmentFileUpload" type="file" size="45" name="LogoUploadedToUpload"
  class="imguploader" onchange="return validateFormToUpload();" />
  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ValidationGroup="SendMailValidationGroup"
   ControlToValidate="AttachmentFileUpload" ErrorMessage="Attachment Is Required." CssClass="errorMessage"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
   CssClass="errorMessage"></asp:Label>
```

and I have tried this and in this context it works fine

```
    <asp:FileUpload ID="AttachmentFileUpload" runat="server"></asp:FileUpload>
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="UploadButton" Text="Upload" OnClientClick="return validateFormToUpload();" />
```

But my problem arises here when i use asp:fileuploader the page shows error and when i use html input it works fine and I have decided to use html control. Now the problem is How can I validate html file `<input type="file"/>`? Any solution are surely appretiated and I have googled for the solution but I didn't get any answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below code

HTML

```
<input id="fileSelect" type="file" >
```

jQuery code

```
$('#fileSelect').change(function(){   
    if($(this).val() == '')
        alert('no file');
    else
        alert('file');
});
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AxPQ6/3/)